# Invoice paid in full are re-opened when we ran scheduled script on the old invoices

Tags: netsuite

We ran a scheduled script on all the invoices from 2019 & 2020, which actually updates the custom line fields on the invoices.

when we ran this script, some of the statuses of the invoice moved from paid in full to open.

I don't how to switch it back, the payments are already applied to them.

Did anyone face this problem in Netsuite

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the support here.

I found the issue, we were not using AVATAX in 2019 and when I ran my script the tax got calculated again by avatax and it's showing as due. That is why they got re-opened.

I found the solution to fix them by unchecking the tax on Item lines, then the status changed back to paid in full.